# How to read Simplified Mandarin Chinese characters From text file and save mp3 file using say command on Mac

Tags: javascript, applescript

I am using Javascript.  I have little experience with JavaScript and this is my first time trying to write a script.  The Chinese text is not properly read in using this method.  For example "他是一位非常著名的演员" gets saved as "‰ªñÊòØ‰∏Ä‰ΩçÈùûÂ∏∏ËëóÂêçÁöÑÊºîÂëò.aiff".  I also know the pronunciation is not correct using this method.  I've read [this](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/LanguagesUtilities/Conceptual/MacAutomationScriptingGuide/SpeakText.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40016239-CH62-SW1) documentation and have searched around but can't find anything about this issue.  I also have no idea how to write an mp3 file.

```
var app = Application.currentApplication();
app.includeStandardAdditions = true;

var basePath = "path to directory";
var inputPath = basePath + "/input.txt";
var text = app.read(inputPath).split("\n");

for (let i = 0; i < text.length; i++) {
    var recordingPath = basePath + "/" + text[i] + ".aiff";
    app.say(text[i], {savingTo: recordingPath});
    app.say(text[i]);
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

It looks like an encoding issue. The script doesn't know what it's trying to read so you have to tell it that it's encoded as `«class utf8»`. I don't use javascript so I can't help you with its syntax but in applescript, it would look like this.

```
read file inputPath as «class utf8»
--> "他是一位非常著名的演员"
```

The audio stuff is separate but even if you don't know how to record to mp3, you have some conversion options. itunes can convert AIFF to mp3. I'm not sure whether the shell command `afconvert` can convert to mp3 (doesn't look promising) but it can convert to m4a.

Comment: Thank you.  Your comment helped me find this and that did the trick https://github.com/JXA-Cookbook/JXA-Cookbook/issues/25#issuecomment-271204038